# npm shows an error 'ENOENT: no such file or directory' when creating a react project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install, npx

I've installed Node.js for Windows and I'm trying to create a new React project via npm. Upon typing 'npx create-react-app projectName', I receive the following error:

`ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm'`

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Comment: Did you install the npm? Use `npm -v` to check

Comment: Yes, I have installed the node.js and checked using `npm -v`

Answer (score 10):

I got the exact same error with `npx nuxi@latest init my-app` and the solution was surprisingly simple. Just create that missing directory.

```
mkdir "%AppData%\npm"
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the exact same error in my Next.js project.
The following command worked:

```bash
npm install npm -g
```

Later on I got a similar error in my project so I re-built the project:

```bash
npm run build
```

Comment: Fixed this for me today, thank you. For those wondering the -g flag installs it "globally" on your machine, you likely only have it installed for your current user before running this command.